# provide option to plot or display a image in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

i have written this shiny app in which i want to provide option to choose to plot an output or display an image in main panel, but this is not working, any idea where this option could be added ?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("time-profilling"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(   
      selectInput("vari", "x-Variable:",
              c("M","N","K","heatmap" )),
    uiOutput("ui1"),
    uiOutput("ui2")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    if(input$vari == "M" || input$vari == "N" || input$vari == "K" ){
      plotlyOutput("results", height = "800px", width = "800px")
    }
    else if(input$vari == "heatmap"){
      imageOutput("image1")
      imageOutput("image2")
    }  
  )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really enough in your example to work with - some data or some plotting would help a quite a bit. But here are two thoughts and a structure for your code that will hopefully get you started down the right path...

1. You can't put any logic in the UI of a shiny app. Ifelse statements should all be in the server, which you don't have here.
2. That server code should be paired to each output you have (plots or images), as below.

Revised and additional code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("time-profilling"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(   
      selectInput("vari", "x-Variable:",
                  c("M","N","K","heatmap" )),
      uiOutput("ui1"),
      uiOutput("ui2")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput("results", height = "800px", width = "800px"),
        imageOutput("image1"),
        imageOutput("image2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$results <- renderPlotly({
    if(input$vari == "M" || input$vari == "N" || input$vari == "K" ) {
      ## Plotly code goes here
    }
    return(NULL)
  })

  output$image1 <- renderImage({
    if(input$vari == "heatmap"){
      ## Pre-rendered image code goes here
    }
    return(NULL)
  })

  output$image2 <- renderImage({
    if(input$vari == "heatmap"){
      ## Pre-rendered image code goes here
    }
    return(NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Right now the inputs don't provide anything, because you need to input code to draw your plots or find your images, but the structure should work fine.